# access $primary in library as set by custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I work with nrwl/nx and have independent libraries.

In my main app, i define a theme for material.

Now in my lib, i want to use the $primary color as set by this theme, without importing the theme. The lib should stay independen and work in other apps using other themes as well.

So what i want to do in a component in my library is i.e.:

```
libs/foo/.../bar.component/scss:
.header {
  background-color: $primary;
}
```

Using the theme defined in the app, in a custom theme like this:

```
apps/bar/custom-theme.scss
...
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-red);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-green);
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-amber);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-app-primary,
    accent: $my-app-accent,
    warn: $my-app-warn,
  )
));
```

I am using @angular/material@10.0.2

Comment: `background-color: mat-color($my-app-primary)` to get your color.

Comment: I tried that but it complains that it doesn't know `$my-app-primary`. Also, this would not work if some other theme ist used that does not use `$my-app-primary`

Comment: You should import your variables (@import....) inside your component scss. Then to use 2 themes or more take a look at https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes & https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context . If you have any question I can help you out.

Comment: @Myerffoeg i could define custom variables in my project and import them in the library, but i want the library to be independent, thus independent of custom variables.
I want to use the material theme variables of the chosen theme.